# Python Openshift Multiple webpages

Tags: python, openshift, redhat

New to python and openshift.  I can follow the directions easy enough to edit the wsgi.py file ([directions](https://developers.openshift.com/languages/python/getting-started.html)).  However I'm not sure what to do if I want to add more webpages to this.  If I go to mydomain.rhcloud.com it will display my wsgi.py file.  However I want to add web pages to this.  So something like mydomain.rhcloud.com/webpage1 and mydomain.rhcloud.com/webpage2.  Can someone please instruct me on how to set this up?
Thanks so much!

Comment: Search Github for my fatfantasma Pyramid starter. Sry.  Don't have link at moment.

Comment: Found it; ) https://github.com/fatfantasma/Openshift-Pyramidstarter

Comment: Which file should I look at?

Comment: That starter uses the Pyramid framework for web development and how to set up on Openshift.  You now need to read the Pyramid docs to understand everything.

Comment: OK.  I'm really new and this code is a bit too complex for me.  Is there an easier way? At any rate thanks for your help!

Comment: Take a look at Flask framework.  Or real simple, without using a framework just create your webpage1.html and webpage2.html files and access them like in your question. I think you need to do some reading tho: ) there are plenty of examples.

Comment: Ok thanks so much for your help!